# How to draw a rectangle on image at specific location and size?

Tags: c#, winforms

tried this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Weather
{
    public class DrawDateTime
    {
        public DrawDateTime()
        {
            string fileName = @"e:\radar_without_clouds.jpg";//...
            int width = 0;//...
            int height = 0;//...

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(
                width, height,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb); // or some other format
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black))
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 140, 21)); // whatever
                                                                                    // and so on...
                } // myBrush will be disposed at this line
                bitmap.Save(fileName);
            } // graphics will be disposed at this
        }
    }
}
```

using it in form1

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DrawDateTime datetime  = new DrawDateTime();
        }
```

but getting error exception on the line :

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(
                width, height,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at Weather.DrawDateTime..ctor() in E:\Csharp Projects\wt\DrawDateTime.cs:line 18
   at Weather.Form1..ctor() in E:\Csharp Projects\wt\Form1.cs:line 57
   at Weather.Program.Main() in E:\Csharp Projects\wt\Program.cs:line 19
```

what i want to do is to draw a rectangle and fill it in black at specific location on image and then to write some text inside the drawn black rectangle in yellow with specific size of the text.

exmaple of image with black rectangle and yellow text inside at the top left corner.  but i want to be able to write my own text.  the same as it is in the image but with my own text. whatever text i want to write on it instead what is written now.

for example to write on the image on the top left corner in yellow in that size the current date time.

[image: example of the image i want to write my own text in yellow instead the text in the top left corner.]

Comment: Did you actually set the `Width` and `Height` of the Bitmap to `0`? -- Note that this: `bitmap.Save(fileName);` generates a PNG image, not a JPEG. You have to specify `ImageFormat.Jpeg` to get a JPEG image.

Comment: working ! found how to do it.